# Why is there a letter 'R' on the rooftop?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

In the ending part in Episode 1 of *The Quintessential Quintuplets*, there is an upper case of letter 'R' on the rooftop of the department where the quints live.

[image]

It looks pretty much like the landing pads in [GTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_(video_game)).

[image]

Is it actually a landing pad? Are there usually landing pads on the rooftops of those high-rise department buildings where the really rich live in Japan? What I mean here is not the building owned by a millionaire individual but the building where many rich people buy or rent their apartments and live.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't landing pad.

Normally, landing pads are roughly 1.2 to 1.3 times the size of the helicopter  on which they are operated (IIRC), but where this type is marked, they are not that size. Therefore, helicopters cannot land on them, but some places are marked with this notation as a place for ***R***escue operations in a hovering state.